# Custom Field on Social Table

Tags: social-tables

I'm trying to add custom field on event and guest.I have seen add custom field option for guest on checkin.socialtables.com. but that's not showing anywhere to me.Can someone help how can we create fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create up to 10 custom fields for the guests on your guestlist (Social Tables does not currently offer custom fields at the event level). To create, edit, or delete a custom field, open a guest detail modal by clicking on any guest in your guestlist. Scroll to the bottom of the modal to find the Custom Field section, and click the green plus button to open the Custom Field form. Enter a name for the field and click Done. Now the field exists on all guests in the guestlist.

There is one other way to create custom fields: if you import a spreadsheet of guests into Checkin, you will have the option to import any columns in the spreadsheet as custom fields.